# Does there exist a pyramid with 18 equal edges?

Tags: geometry

Can you build a pyramid using 18 sticks of equal length?
Dutch schoolbook says no. I am not convinced.
Nobody says the 9-gon in the base has to be regular.

Comment: I don't get it. If the nonagon isn't regular, how can the sticks have the same length?

Comment: can we glue two sticks to make a longer one?

Comment: @PseudoNeo regular means same length *and* same angles. Think of a (nonsquare) rhombus.

Comment: You can make a regular tetrahedron with 18 sticks of equal length, just use three sticks for each of the six edges.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one?

[image]

Base is a regular hexagon, six "spokes" each consist of two sticks.

Answer (score 0):

Take the point of the pyramid as a starting point, and drop a perpendicular to the plane containing the base (if the base doesn't lie in a plane, it isn't a pyramid, right). Use Pythagoras to show that the points in the plane (which are equally distant from the point) must lie on a circle. Alternatively a sphere (defined by the point and the length of a side) cuts a plane in a circle.

But note that the problem is not necessarily confined to this as specified. The sticks could (?) be joined together so you had different integer lengths. I can make a pyramid with a triangular base of side $1$ and diagonal sides of length $5$, for example.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. But the kids have not had the  Pythagoras theorem yet. It is only September.

Comment: @user28425 It depends how rigorous you want to be - there was no reference to kids in the question, and I cited the alternative that the intersection of a plane and a sphere is a circle, which is intuitively obvious: but for serious mathematics you need to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

A pyramid with 18 equal edges could be formed if 9 equilateral triangles stood on the edges of a regular 9-gon *and* those 9 triangles close up nicely, without leaving any gaps or overlapping. In particular, the top vertices meet in a single point, and slant edges are aligned nicely.

But each top vertex angle is $60^{\circ}$. This means there is now $9\times60=540$ degrees at a single point! Angle sum larger than $360^{\circ}$ at a point is impossible, and hence the 18-pyramid.

To better understand this, let's see how a cone is made. Cut away a minor sector from a circular piece of paper, and bring the edges together. Clearly, the vertex angle at the apex of the cone (along the blue surface) is less than $360^{\circ}$. The angle by which sum of angles at any vertex, where adjacent faces of a polyhedron meet, fail to sum to $360^{\circ}$ is called [angular defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect).

[image]

As any polyhderon can be made by cutting and gluing together polygons, because the polygons meeting at a single vertex are no more in the horizontal plane, they fold up to give a sum of angles *strictly less than* $360^{\circ}$. Thus there will always be positive angular defect. See the list of angular defects for regular polyhedra in the link above. One example, vertex angles of three adjacent faces of a cube sum to $90^{\circ}+90^{\circ}+90^{\circ}=270^{\circ}<360^{\circ}$.

Thus such a regular 18-pyramid is impossible to form.

Note that gluing the sticks is not allowed, since then the number of edges will come down from 18. I doubt the book will overlook the trivial case of the tetrahedron. 6 equal sticks can be joined to give a regular tetrahedron with 4 equilateral triangles as faces. Then glue 3 sticks per edge to make a regular pyramid with 18 sticks. But it is only a tetrahedron!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pyramid with 18 equal edges:

[image]

Comment: Clever diagram, +1! It shows the 18-pyramid is possible by overlapping. Though non-overlapping pyramid is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

We may not he able to get a pyramid with 18 unit edges, but a truncated pyramid us fair game.  The illustration below us from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_tetrahedron).  Created by user [Cyp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en:User:Cyp) using this [Creative Commons license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).

[image]